# Pygame - Is it possible to create everything in one surface and scale it down to display surface?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, geometry, pygame-surface

I wish to draw a few circles of large radius on the screen using pygame. I would like to define a surface called `surface1` larger than my display surface (`screen`) and plot my circles in the actual dimension. Once I do that I am planning to rescale `surface1` and display it on `screen`.  Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
live = True
while live:
    surface1 = pygame.Surface((7680, 4320))
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
    # pygame.display.flip()
    surface1.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.draw.circle(surface1, (0, 0, 0), (3839, 2160), 4500, 10)
    surface1 = pygame.transform.scale(surface1, (1280, 720))
    surface1.convert()
    screen.blit(surface1, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            live = False
```

For some reason I can't see the circle. However, the color of the displayed window changes according to what I set inside `surface1`. Why is this behaving that way? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle is bigger than the big surface. The pos argument is the center of the circle and the radius is larger than half of both the width and the height. Try to draw something smaller.

Also, manipulating such a huge surface will result in very poor performance.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that. Thanks. But say the circle has a radius 1500. Is this the right logic?

Comment: @Syamprasad K R yes it will work with a smaller circle, but because of the big surface and the transform the frame rate will be very low. Why do you actually do that?

Comment: This is to solve an engineering problem and the actual dimensions are big. I am trying to avoid scaling down all factors. But that's what I am doing now.

Comment: Interesting. If you need more help feel free to post a new question.